# POST a javascript objet to a PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I try to post an JS object to PHP, but the PHP says nothing.. It looks like it don't recognize the POST...

Here is the JS :

```
$('.send').click(function() {
    var Scommand = JSON.stringify(command);// Command is my JS obj

    if (commande.type) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'test.php',
            context:$(this),
            type:'POST',
            data:Scommande,
            success : function(data){
                commande = {};
                window.location='test.php';
            }
        });//End Ajax
    }
    else {'PLz specify a type');}
});
```

And my PHP  :

```
<?php
echo $_POST['type'];
?>
```

It returns : Notice: Undefined index: type in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BackOfficeDavid/test.php on line 2

Like nothing go throw the POST ... Any clue ?

Comment: data:{mydata: Scommand},  and look at $_POST['mydata']

Comment: It's a paste mistake :) 
Commande is composed by commande.type, commande.obj & command.header... 
@Cheery it didn't works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're converting the command to a string. The data on the ajax call has to be a JSON object, not a string. What you can do is pass the command variable directly:

```
var command = { type: "whatever" };

$.ajax({
    url:'test.php',
    context:$(this),
    type:'POST',
    data: command,
    success: function(data){
       command = {};
       window.location='test.php';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable/remove `window.location='test.php';`.

What might be happening is that the success callback is called, redirecting you to the `test.php` after everything is actually done. This would be a plain move to `test.php`, by `GET`, so there will be no parameters in `$_POST`.

---

Actually, better yet, replace `window.location='test.php';` with `alert(data)`, so you'll see what is returned. Otherwise it will seem like nothing happened since the ajax just completes successfully and silently in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean

```
data:'type=' + encodeURIComponent(Scommande),
```

instead of

```
data:Scommande,
```

This will [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the `Scommande` variable and assign its value to the `type` POST variable.

Alternatively, you can rely on jQuery to do that for you by using

```
data: {'type': Scommande},
```

(PS. Not sure if the variable is meant to be named `Scommand` or `Scommande`. You probably have a typo somewhere)